# using a loop result as a variable for child loop

Tags: django, django-templates

I think the best way to describe is problem is with an example.

```
{% for content in contents %}
  {% for stuff in {{content}} %}
    {{stuff}}
  {% endfor %}  
{% endfor %}
```

I am using google app engine webapp templates. I can't seem to use a result from the parent forloop `{{content}}` as a variable for its child forloop. `TemplateSyntaxError: Could not parse the remainder: '{{content}}' from '{{content}}'` Is it possible to do this? Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use only `content` without braces around:

```
{% for content in contents %}
  {% for stuff in content %}
    {{ stuff }}
  {% endfor %}  
{% endfor %}
```

When you are inside the first for-loop, `content` exists in the context, as any other variable. Same thing for `stuff` in the inner loop. Plus, blocks are generally using argument as variables, except in it is surrounded by quotes.
The `{{  }}` notation can be use to only display the variable in the document.

Comment: Thanks Maxime. I'm been trying this code an it looks promising. One question though...say the first output `for content in contents` contains the word 'math'  . Would this make the inner loop `{% for stuff in math %}`   ? It doesn't seem to be working this way.

Comment: Yes. If `contents = ['math', 'physics']` then `content` will be `"math"` at the first iteration (and so the inner loop will iterate over each character, Python string are iterable), and then `"physics"` at the second iteration.

Comment: I think that's the problem I'm having actually, my output is  m  a  t  h. It's like the loop is doing one character at a time, is there a way to make it so it does the entire word at once?

Comment: As I said, if you have a list of words, one loop is enough to have the whole word each time ;)

Comment: Also, I'm not sure if this is important, but content and math are in the same dictionary, but as different entries. In another words, the inner loop: `{% for stuff in math %}` gives me a different result than `{% for stuff in content.name %}`

Comment: And when I type `{% for content in contents %}//{{content.name}}//{% endfor %}` The first output is math, then science, history, etc.